# On Which Side Will The Tyre Wear Out More?

Tags: materials, automotive-engineering, friction, traction

Whilst watching a F1 race recently I noticed the commentators talk about how all the cars on that race day started observing more/faster wearing down of the tyres on the front left of the car relative to the other tyres on the car. It got me thinking about how the track lay out affects tyre wear.

**Question**:
Can we predict on which side of the car (left or right & front or back) will the tyre wear down more based on the number of 'right/left turns' & total distance of 'straights'?

**My attempt to rationalize the question is as follows**:
If there are predominantly right hand turns, the tyres on the left hand side should wear down more/faster as there will be a load transfer to the left hand side of the car during a right hand turn due to centrifugal effects.
Similarly if there are longer straights, I think the back tyres should wear down more/faster as during acceleration in the straights, the load transfer will occur towards the back of the car due to inertia.

Comment: Wbat about surface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually a right turn puts more weight of the left side of the car, however that is not the only parameter.

Equally important is the speed as you approach the curb and start to apply the brakes, and also the speed that you engage the turn. So if you had the same amount of left and right turns but the right turns are at higher speed then you'd expect the left set of tires to be more worn out.

Also another factor is how much does the driver go over the sausage curb.

[image]

Comment: Ahh yes how could I forget about the speed factor! Thanks!